# Detect mouse movement direction in JPanel

Tags: java, mouse, direction

How do i detect mouse movement direction and print in console or set text in JTextField like: "Mouse moved left" in JPanel at mouseMoved event ?

Edit: I founded the right code:

```
private int oldX = 0;
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        if(oldX > e.getX())
        {
            System.out.println("Mouse moved left");
        }

        if(oldX < e.getX())
        {
            System.out.println("Mouse moved right");
        }
        oldX = e.getX();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us your code and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Obviously going to involve a `MouseMotionListner` and and few variables and math involved

Comment: After a few trying i find right code: 
 private int oldX = 0;
 @Override
 public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) 
 {
  if(oldX > e.getX())
  {
   System.out.println("Mouse moved left");
  }
  
  if(oldX < e.getX())
  {
   System.out.println("Mouse moved right");
  }
  oldX = e.getX();
 }                                                                                                                 I'am sorry for bothering....